# How to grant partial or subset access to a web API resource to a user?

Tags: api, access-control, role-based-access-control

I am working on a project where I need to implement access control on web API as follows.

I want to grant partial or subset access to API user. For example

- I have 4 resource in an web API.
- I want to give only 1 and 3 resource access to user X. User should not able to access resource 2 and 4.
- And any resource should not reveal anything about other resource.

How can i achieve above result in a web api. What should be the recommended approach for doing this.

I already went through most of Q&A on SO.

Please help me on this. 
Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.